# Django allauth Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm using django allauth. Everything working fine, except when trying to signup using Google. I got this error: Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid.

[image]

Is there any solution to this?

Here is my Google Developer Console:
[image]

I've also tried to change http to https and it's also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my case, what I have to do is change the Authorized redirect URLs from:

```
http://localhost:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/
```

to

```
http://localhost:8000/google/login/callback/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/google/login/callback/
```

just remove the "accounts/" and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You url is not matching with google url please correct your url in Clound console.

[image]

Comment: I've tried it, but the error is still there

Comment: I've also edited my question

Answer (score 0):

- Check the error details, You will get a **redirect_url** from it.
- Copy the url and paste it in the **Authorised redirect URIs** in **GoogleCloud**.
- Then go to you main page refresh the page and try signing in again.